# Insert/update data in chunks in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions

I have a query which finds the aggregate sum and counts from a table and I need to update these details in another table. If I use the query without any conditions that limit the number of rows fetched at a time, it is failing (timed out) and so I am planning to fetch 10000 records at a time and insert it into the database. Now I have some confusions regarding this.

1. If I use database transactions and include all the operations from fetching the data to insert/update it in db, it is a good idea ? I would like to know whether this will lock the table which I am fetching until the transaction is completed. If so I can't use that as there are other API queries which is acting upon this data in real time.
2. The better way for this operation is through loops ? I mean fetching 1000 records and update 1000 records in DB or I need to use one more layer in between like Redis file storage, which will store the entire data and update operation will be performed at once.

My operation flow in the application level is as follows:

```
while ($i <= $maxCounr) {
    $limit          = 1000;
    $results            = fetchResults($i, $limit);
    $formattedResilts   = formatResults($results);

    updateRecords($formattedResults);

    $i = $i + 1000;
}
```

Is there any downside in doing something like this ? One thing I noted is that it needs to hit database multiple times. If I have 100000 entries to be processed, it needs to hit database `100000/1000 =  100` times. Is there any other way I can do this ? I am using this in a background worker which is running daily basis.